# Access Denied when using Lamda Edge with CloudFront to access S3

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have a CloudFront setup from which I want to serve static file content placed S3 buckets ( will have many sub folders).

I want to route request to different folders within bucket based on query string.
In my Lamda Edge function which I have added as trigger for CloudFront I do following

```
const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
request.origin.s3.path = "/" + folderName + request.uri
callback(null, request);
```

But when I access CloudFront via its url I get "AccessDenied" error. Not sure how to debug this.
My S3 bucket files are public and I can access them using proper s3 urls.

Any help here will be great.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [check the docs for this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-content-based-S3-origin-based-on-query), you need to generate another response which points to s3.

Here is an example from the docs which could be useful for your case:

```
'use strict';

 const querystring = require('querystring');

 exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
     const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;

     /**
      * Reads query string to check if S3 origin should be used, and
      * if true, sets S3 origin properties.
      */

     const params = querystring.parse(request.querystring);

     if (params['useS3Origin']) {
         if (params['useS3Origin'] === 'true') {
             const s3DomainName = 'my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com';

             /* Set S3 origin fields */
             request.origin = {
                 s3: {
                     domainName: s3DomainName,
                     region: '',
                     authMethod: 'none',
                     path: '',
                     customHeaders: {}
                 }
             };
             request.headers['host'] = [{ key: 'host', value: s3DomainName}];
         }
     }

    callback(null, request);
};
```

You would need to change the logic to replace the `s3DomainName` for the path of your file as your code e.g:

```
             /* Set S3 origin fields */
             request.origin = {
                 s3: {
                     domainName: <yourS3Domain>,
                     region: '',
                     authMethod: 'none',
                     path: folderName+ / + request.uri,
                     customHeaders: {}
                 }
             };
             request.headers['host'] = [{ key: 'host', value: <yourS3Domain>}];
```